# Does AWS charge on the basis of number of incoming request or the duration of the session?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Are there charges associated with number of incoming requests or the interval of sessions on aws .All I was able to find was the hourly charges in case of an EC2 instance.

Comment: Charging of AWS services vary, but on their official pricing pages you can always find pretty precise explanations, and usually a few good examples of pricing. In case of EC2, you are charged hourly rate plus storage rate (take a look at EBS pricing for more details)

Comment: What do you mean by "session"? What AWS service are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All I was able to find was the hourly charges in case of an EC2 instance

Lets assume you are interested in EC2 instances.

AWS charges are distributed in 3 categories: computation power, storage, traffic

Computation power:

- for EC2 instances you pay hourly charges
- there are services payed per request (e.g. Lamda, API Gateway, Route53, ..), but for EC2 it's not the case

Storage:

- if you are using EBS backed instance (the instances are having a persistent disk), you pay for the storage
- you may be charged to use provisioned IOPS (high throughput disks) if you choose them
- some storage services are having additional cost per request (S3)
- some storage services are having additional cost for provisioned thorughput (DynamoDB)
- some storage services are spawning computation resources under the hood, so having hourly charge (RDS, Neptune, ..)

Traffic:

- inbound traffic and traffic inside the region (inside your VPC) are free of charge
- outbound traffic is charged approx ~ $0.09 / GB

Free tier:

- many services are having free tier usage, therefore not counting first X hours, request, GBs, ...